# How to set up communication between two Raspberry Pi without internet

Tags: communication, mqtt, p2p

I was trying to learn how to set up communication between two raspberry pi in close proximity in a remote area without a router. I am new to raspberry pi and started trying to figure out MQTT/Mosquitto but upon further research, I think that MQTT needs to be plugged into a router or into every individual pi to operate. I was wondering if I was missing something about MQTT or if I should try to find another method of communication? The goal of this communication is to send a rapidly changing number on a mobile station where a wire cannot be used.

I am currently using 2 Pi Raspberry Zero W running the full install of Raspbian Buster. The system of communication should preferably be wireless communication which can send information with minimal delay.

Example of what I am trying to do for reference:

Having a sensor and pi on one side of a vehicle transmitting sensor info to another pi on the other side of the said vehicle where a wire cannot be used.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details?  Which Raspberry Pi models are you using and what OS are you running?  I am inferring that you want to do this via a wireless mechanism (e.g. WiFi or Bluetooth) because your your last sentence reads "where a wire cannot be used".

Comment: @TimCampbell Added some info, can add more clarification if needed.

Comment: You need to provide more detail, but you can run MQTT between ANY computers. I use a Pi as broker on my local network.

Comment: @Milliways I understand I can run MQTT on the RPi and have successfully done so, but I was wondering if MQTT could be used in a project where there would be no router and no form of wired communication(ethernet) between the 2 RPi. And if not what type of communication should be established.

Comment: You need to have a network.  Possibly an ad-hoc wifi network would suit your needs?

Comment: @user10489 I've looked into ad-hoc networks and was wondering if it was possible to use MQTT on an ad-hoc network? If not am I right to assume that ad-hoc networks can be easily incorporated into python?

Comment: MQTT and python know nothing about your network architecture.   The network is just a data transport mechanism, and set up and control of that network is needed to make this work, but out of scope of either MQTT or python to control.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question about how to set up an ad-hoc wifi network on a set of raspberry pi's.